# If not redirected redirect to original page

Tags: redirecttoaction

i have two pages

1. parameters.php
2. targetparameters.php

people can enter their parameters in the parameters.php and click submit. Which gets redirected to targetparameters.php. this page shows what would be their after one year target.

Now if someone just types in the address bar as targetparameters.php the page shows the last entered entry.

I Want that if someone even types targetparameters.php he should get redirected to parameters.php. but should allow if submit is pressed in parameters.php

Hope so i am not confusing you with this question.

Thanks

Amod (India)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to achieve that would be to use Session Variables.
You need to create a Session Variable for somebody when he clicks on you submit button in `parameters.php`.

Then, in `targetparameters.php`, you will check wether the session variable is defined. If so, then grant access to the visitor and destroy the variable.
If it doesn't exist, then do not grant access.

Here's an exemple (you might need to adapt to your own case) :

In `parameters.php` :

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
[Your code]
// On click on submit, a session is created with 'submit' = "yes";
<input type = "submit" onclick = "<?php $_SESSION['submit'] = "yes"; ?>"
```

In `targetparameters.php` :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['submit'])) {
        [rest of your code]
        session_destroy(); // Destroys the session
    } else {
        echo 'You are unknown';
    }
?>
```

Or, if you want to keep some of the variables, you may use :

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['submit'] ) ) {
    unset( $_SESSION['submit'] );
}
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks But i allready have a session for loggin will it get colided if the onclick session

Comment: Not necessarily. Simply don't use `session_destroy()`, use `unset()`, I've updated the post above to show that.